# classicthesis and scrheadings

Tags: koma-script, classicthesis

When using `classicthesis` I feel that the `spacedlowsmallcaps` (provided by `classicthesis`) take too much control over my typography. I've been able to tweak the section titles to have a capital letter in the beginning. However, I don't seem to be able to get the text in the header to be anything but small caps. Is it possible to customize this?

Any help on this would be highly appreciated!

Here is what I am working on - and I use LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
            % headlines,% letterpaper,% a4paper
            footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
            BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[math]{fontspec}
\newfontlanguage{Norwegian}{NOR}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[parts,beramono,eulerchapternumbers,%
        listings,subfig,manychapters,%
        floatperchapter]{classicthesis} 

\begin{document}
\titleformat{\section}{\relax}{\textsc{\thesection}}{1em}{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-6]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, I've added a working example. Is this OK?

Comment: I am not sure what your objective is. Do you want to get rid of the spaced smallcaps overall? Then simply redefine the command to suit your needs: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\itshape #1}` would set everything into italics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer depends on your objective: If you want to use some other font features at all places where `classicthesis` uses `spacedsmallcaps` the easiest is just to redefine the command: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\itshape #1}` would use simple italics instead of small caps.

If you want to redefine it just for the headers you need to redefine the appropriate command as I demonstrate in the MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
            % 1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
            footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
            BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage[parts,beramono,eulerchapternumbers,%
        listings,subfig,manychapters,%
        floatperchapter]{classicthesis}

% This redefines space low caps completely
% \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\itshape #1}

% This redefines just the header just for chapters
\renewcommand\Chap[2][]{%
                     \ifluatex\oldchap[\texorpdfstring{\textit{#1}}{#1}]{#2}%
                     \else\oldchap[\textit{#1}]{#2}%
                     \fi%
}

% Fontspecs needs to be loaded AFTER classicthesis
\usepackage[math]{fontspec}
\newfontlanguage{Norwegian}{NOR}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}


\begin{document}
\titleformat{\section}{\relax}{\textsc{\thesection}}{1em}{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}

\lipsum[1-6]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
% ********************************************************************
```

Note the following:

- It's `documentclass`, not `Documentclass`
- `Fontspec` must be loaded *after* `classicthesis`
- No need to load `fontspec` twice
- In this MWE I just redefine the headings for chapters. You may want to to the same for `tocEntry` and `PartS`.

Comment: Wow. Thans. I did in deed only want to change the header text. And your answer helped do just that. Sorry about the capital D in documentclass. Happens sometimes when I copy from Emacs. And thank you also for the heads up on fontspec. though I thought it was enough to define the fonts I use after classicthesis.